# MCP23017 working sporadically

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

So I've got two MCP23017's on the same I2C bus connected to a RPi. One is addressed 0x20, the other 0x24. The RPi is running my GUI which in turn controls the MCP's which switch 16-way relay boards.

The GUI is written in python and using the Adafruit_GPIO MCP230XX library
The 0x20 MCP is located next to the RPi, and powered by the same power supply and works like a charm. (a 5V 5A power supply)

But, the 0x24 MCP is located about 2 meters (~ 6.5') away, with the 5v, GND, SCL and SDA lines taken in CAT5 from the RPi. The relay board is powered separately, with the GND's connected. But, this little arse doesn't want to work at all. The RPi can see the MCP (i2cdetect), but it doesn't seem to respond. Very occasionally it will start working, but when I unplugged a load from the same socket that is powering everything it cut out and stopped working again?!? I've even rebuilt the board with a new MCP chip and it's changed nothing. Is this me being dumb somewhere?

Any and all help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Does the distant board have pullup resistors on the SCL & SDA lines at the remote end?

Comment: Do you have a power supply bypass capacitor on the far end device?

Comment: You have omitted a lot of info. What pullups there are on I2C bus? Do you have a schematic? What I2C bus speed? Is there any level translation between 3.3V Raspi and 5V MCP chips? Which CAT5 wires you are using for which purpose?

Comment: @CrossRoads I don't, no. Would you reckon 10k resistors would be a good starting point?

Comment: It depends a) to what voltage you are connecting them to and b) do you already have pullup resistors at all. I2C buses do not generally need resistors at both ends of a bus anyway. Also what you need to know if Raspberry is 5V tolerant or will it blow up.

Comment: @Justme Apologies for the lack of information; it's been a while since I was taught this. Currently, there are no pull-ups on the I2C. I think you're right about the RPi not being a lover of 5V, so will drop the MCPs to 3.3V (which it's happy with). I also forgot the decoupling capacitors, so will add them. Will see if this helps

Comment: If no resistors at all right now, then use 3.3K or 2.7K to 3.3V.

Comment: Big thanks @CrossRoads, it's all working now! I think it was a combination of all the above, due to my idiocy haha. Thanks again